# How to access DynamoDB by authenticated cognito user (user pool) in swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use AWS Cognito(User Pools) and AWS DynamoDB for my mobile apps.

I did the following:

1. Create User Pools on AWS Cognito.
2. Create identity pool on AWS Cognito and set User Pool Id, App Client Id to Cognito on Authentication Provider.
3. Create SampleTable on AWS DynamoDB.
4. Set Permission Authenticated Role to access SampleTable on AWS IAM.

I created this code:

```
let userPoolConfigration = AWSServiceConfiguration.init(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = userPoolConfigration

let userServiceConfigration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration.init(clientId: "(client id from user pool)", clientSecret: "(client secret from user pool)", poolId: "(user pool id from user pool)")

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithUserPoolConfiguration(userServiceConfigration, forKey: "AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider")
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider")

    let user = pool.getUser("sampleuser")
    user.getSession("sampleuser", password: "samplepassword", validationData: nil, scopes: nil).continueWithBlock({ task in
        if (task.error == nil) {
            let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
                identityPoolId:"(identity id from identity pool)")

            let ret = task.result as! AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession
            let logins: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/(user pool id from user pool)" : ret.idToken!.tokenString])
            credentialsProvider.logins = logins as [NSObject : AnyObject]
            let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
            credentialsProvider.clearKeychain()
            credentialsProvider.credentials().continueWithBlock {(task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                let result = task.result as! AWSCredentials
                let newcredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey:result.accessKey, secretKey: result.secretKey)
                let newdefaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: newcredentialsProvider)
                AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = newdefaultServiceConfiguration

                let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
                let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()

                dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(SampleTable.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWithBlock({ task in
                    print(task.result)
                    return nil
                })
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
```

But I got this error when "dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan()" was run:

```
2016-06-23 16:57:04.988 AWSiOSSDK v2.4.3 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:525 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request headers:
{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.0";
    Host = "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.4.3 iPhone-OS/9.2 en_US mapper";
    "X-Amz-Date" = 20160623T075704Z;
    "X-Amz-Target" = "DynamoDB_20120810.Scan";
}
2016-06-23 16:57:04.988 if-she[3704:367618] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.3 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:542 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request body:
{"TableName":"SampleTable"}
2016-06-23 16:57:05.844 AWSiOSSDK v2.4.3 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:552 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersForResponse:] | Response headers:
{
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 125;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.0";
    Date = "Thu, 23 Jun 2016 07:57:05 GMT";
    Server = Server;
    "x-amz-crc32" = 2088342776;
    "x-amzn-RequestId" = FPM78JRBQIKG2DOLI62SL4IRMFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG;
}
2016-06-23 16:57:05.845 AWSiOSSDK v2.4.3 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#MissingAuthenticationTokenException","message":"Request is missing Authentication Token"}
```

Maybe I am missing how to use Authentication Token.
What is wrong with my code?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding session token to `newcredentialsProvider`? You will have this in the result along with access key and secret key.

Besides that, once you have added the Cognito credentials provider as `defaultServiceConfiguration`, you do not need to explicitely get credentials. You can directly create the `dynamoDBObjectMapper` instance and the SDK will automatically pull temporary credentials from Cognito when calling Dynamo or any other AWS service.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The initialize method of AWSStaticCredentialsProvider haven't parameter sessionKey.
So I delete the code "initialize AWSStaticCredentialsProvider" and "regist defaultServiceConfiguration it"
But I was got Same Error.